# Android text punctuation error

Tags: android, symbols, punctuation

Im getting weird text diplays in my android program. Every so often I get a weird symbol thats a capital A with a ^ on top....any ideas?

This is my code

```
    package com.news;



import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class NewsActivity extends Activity {
    WebView mWebView;
    String test2 = "<html><body><table border=0 width=10 height=10>";
    Document docs;
    Document writing;

    String text(String link)
    {
    String full ="<html><body><table border=0 cellpadding=2 cellspacing=2 height = 10><tr><td>";;
    try {
         writing = Jsoup.connect(link).get();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Element heading = writing.select("h2").first();
    Elements classname = writing.getElementsByClass("news");
    Elements items = classname.select("p");

    full = full + heading.toString() + "<br>" + items.get(0).toString() + "</td></tr>";
    Element imgs2 = writing.select("div.News img").first();

    //Elements imgs2 = writing.select("img[src$=.jpg]");
    String picture = imgs2.absUrl("src");
    String newImg = "<img src=\"" + picture + "\"/ width =100 >";
    full = full + "<tr><td>" + newImg + "</td></tr>";
    full = full + "<tr><td>";

    for (int i = 1; i< items.size(); i++)
    {
        full = full + items.get(i).toString();
    }

    full = full + "</td></tr></table></body></html>";
    return full;
}
public void main(String... args) 
{
    try 
    {
         docs = Jsoup.connect("http://www.dcu.ie/news/index.shtml").get();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //Elements imgs = docs.select("img");
    Elements imgs = docs.select("div.news-feature img");

    //Elements imgs = docs.select("img[src$=.jpg]");
    Elements txt = docs.select("h2");

    Elements article = docs.getElementsByClass("date");
    Elements links = article.select("a[href]");

    for (int i = 0; i < imgs.size(); i++){
        String url = imgs.get(i).absUrl("src");
        String temp = links.get(i).absUrl("href");

        String temp2 = "<a href=\"" + temp + "\"/>";
        String newImg = temp2 + "<img src=\"" + url + "\"/ width =100 >";
        test2 = test2 + "<tr>";

        test2 = test2 + "<td>";
        test2 = test2 + " " + newImg + " ";
        test2 = test2 + "</td>";
        test2 = test2 + "<td><h6>";
        test2 = test2 + txt.get(i).toString();
        test2 = test2 + "</h6></td>";
        test2 = test2 + "</tr>";

        }
    test2 = test2 + "</table>";
    test2 = test2 + "</html></body>";

}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    main();

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new NewsClient());
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    mWebView.loadData(test2, "text/html", "utf-8");

}


@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

private class NewsClient extends WebViewClient {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        String newUrl = text(url);
        view.loadData(newUrl, "text/html", "utf-8");
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer but you should have a valid html.

```
String full ="<html><body><table border='0' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='2' height='10'><tr><td>";
```

put the content of parameters between ' or ".

Second why do you call loadData with 'text/html' and 'utf-8'. While the content at this [url](http://www.dcu.ie/news/index.shtml) is not utf-8 but iso-8859-1. That said you're loading the wrong encoding and thus it display things wrong.

Comment: So like this? mWebView.loadData(test2, "text/html", "iso-8859-1");
It still diplays wrong though? Thanks for the html tips Im new to this!

Comment: Well you should see if JSoup actually loads things correctly first.

Comment: I tried changing it in the program and the xml but still have the error....the funny thing is the main article text displays fine its only these headings...

Comment: My problem goes awayy when I use loadDataWithBaseUrl however the back button doesnt work when I use that it just exits the program?